# JavaFX: aligning labels containing graphics

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to make labels contained in an HBox ignore the graphic when aligned to baseline?

I'm trying to align the labels using their text. What I get instead is that the label with graphics is aligned with a vertical offset with regard to the other labels in a row:

```
<HBox alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" fillHeight="false">
  <children>
    <Button text="Button" />
    <Label text="Label" />
    <Button text="Button">
      <font><Font size="12.0" /></font>
      <graphic>
        <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="15.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="15.0" />
      </graphic>
    </Button>
  </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Did you try changing the [ContentDisplay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#contentDisplayProperty--) property?

Comment: Yep. The culprit appears to be in LabeledSkinBase#calculateBaselineOffset where it adjusts the label's baseline. I can't think of any solution better than overriding the skin for the label.

Comment: But then I'd need to subclass the skin for each Labeled subtype, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes you would Alex.  Perhaps the current behavior is a [bug](http://bugreport.java.com)?

Comment: Bug reported, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172849